# Deploy SvelteKit App to Vercel, could not resolve install-fetch

Tags: vercel, sveltekit

When deploying my SvelteKit app to Vercel I get the following error:

> ```
> > Using @sveltejs/adapter-vercel
> ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "@sveltejs/kit/install-fetch"
>
>      .svelte-kit/vercel-tmp/render/serverless.js:1:29:
>        1 │ import { installFetch } from '@sveltejs/kit/install-fetch';
>          ╵                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   The path "./install-fetch" is not exported by package "@sveltejs/kit":
>      node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/package.json:59:13:
>        59 │   "exports": {
>           ╵              ^   You can mark the path "@sveltejs/kit/install-fetch" as external to exclude it from the
>  bundle, which will remove this error. error during build: Error: Build
>  failed with 1 error: .svelte-kit/vercel-tmp/render/serverless.js:1:29:
>  ERROR: Could not resolve "@sveltejs/kit/install-fetch"
>      at failureErrorWithLog (/vercel/path0/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1603:15)
>      at /vercel/path0/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1249:28
>      at runOnEndCallbacks (/vercel/path0/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1162:65)
>      at buildResponseToResult (/vercel/path0/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1247:7)
>      at /vercel/path0/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1356:14
>      at /vercel/path0/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:666:9
>      at handleIncomingPacket (/vercel/path0/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:763:9)
>      at Socket.readFromStdout (/vercel/path0/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:632:7)
>      at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
>      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12) Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
> ```

The app runs locally (npm run dev). Before updating to a newer version of SvelteKit I was able to deploy to Vercel successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was using an old adapter. `npm install @sveltejs/adapter-auto@1.0.0-next.83` fixed it.